# Computation of the probability of Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to solve the following :

Independent trials that result in a success with probability $p$ and a failure with probability $1-p$ are called Bernoulli trials. Let $P_n$ denote the probability that
n-Bernoulli trials result in an even number of successes (0 being considered an even number). Show that:

$P_n=p(1-P_{n-1})+(1-p)P_{n-1}$ for $n \leq 1$

and use this formula to prove (by induction) that:

$P_n = \frac{1+(1-2p)^{n}}{2}$

My attempt

In the first part I want to say that if the first trial is a success, then the remaining $n-1$ must result in a odd number of successes, whereas If it is a failure then then $n-1$ must result in a even number of successes.

For the second part I have that $P_1 =\frac{1+(1-2p)}{2} = 1-p$, then we assumed that the formula is true for $n-1$ then:

$p(1-\frac{1+(1-2p)^{n-1}}{2}) + (1-p)(\frac{1+(1-2p)^{n-1}}{2})=p-(1+(1-2p)^{n-1})[\frac{p}{2}+\frac{1-p}{2}]=p-\frac{1+(1-2p)^{n-1}}{2}$

Then my questions are Can you help me to accomplish the proof of both parts? please, thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

Comment: Is $P_n$ as sum of Bernoulli trials up to n'th attempt?

Comment: It is the probability that the n-Bernoulli trials result in an even number of successes, then I think you are right :)

Comment: If trials are independent, then the outcome of n'th trial isn't influenced by the previous ones; it makes sense to talk about sums of bernoulli trials, e.g 1+0+0+ $\ldots $+1=n

Comment: right they are independent :)

Comment: Do this https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120216073536AAL7aWH help ?

Comment: The recursion is simply a translation of your statement into symbols, though you have a typo.  You probably intended $n \ge 1$ or $n \gt 1$ rather than $n \le 1$.

Comment: I dont understand very much your comment :(, thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: The basic result is also asked for in [probability that a random variable is even](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149270/probability-that-a-random-variable-is-even) and [the one solution posted there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1149346/15941) uses the method of proof sought here.

Comment: thanks a lot :), and is my attempt for part 1 right ? or what do I have to modify or complete ?, and can you help me to do it please ?:)