# Crossover propability BSC cascade

Tags: information-theory

I was wondering how I could calculate the crossover probability of a **cascade** of $N$ binary symmetric channels.
The crossover probability in every channel is $\epsilon$.

I read the result should equal $\epsilon (n)= \frac{1}{2}(1-(1-2\epsilon)^n)$.
Unfortunately, my calculations do not lead that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of crossovers follows a Binomial distribution $B(N,\epsilon)$ A global crossover occurs if that number is odd. The probability of that event (well, its complement) is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149270/probability-that-a-random-variable-is-even). And it leads to the result you copied.